# Managing events in flutter's TextFormField

Tags: dart, listener, textfield, flutter

In Flutter project, I need to listen to the input text in TextFormField and do certain actions, especially when user put some character (eg. space) in this filed or when he request focus. When this kind of event happen, I need to modify filed's value.
I know there is a property `called controller` but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can specify a controller and focus node, then add listeners to them to monitor for changes.

Ex:

Define controllers and focus nodes

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

FocusNode _textFocus = new FocusNode();
```

Define listener function

```
void onChange(){
  String text = _controller.text;
  bool hasFocus = _textFocus.hasFocus;
  //do your text transforming
  _controller.text = newText;
  _controller.selection = new TextSelection(
                                baseOffset: newText.length, 
                                extentOffset: newText.length
                          );
}
```

Add listner to controller and focusnode at `initState`

```
// you can have different listner functions if you wish
_controller.addListener(onChange); 
_textFocus.addListener(onChange);
```

Then you can use it as

```
new TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  focusNode: _textFocus,
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works. But every time when I change text using `_controller.text = 'some text'`, the cursor goes at the beginning of input field. Why? How can I move it to the end?

Comment: Ok, in this case, the cursor can be moved to the end by `selection` like this: `_controller.selection = new TextSelection(baseOffset: _controller.text.lenght, extentOffset: _controller.text.lengh);`

Comment: Ah! forgot, changed my answer to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, now the answer is perfect :)

Comment: If i have multiple TextFormFileds then should i create controller for each one of them?

Comment: If you want to listen to them all, then yes, you need to create. Or if you want the data when form is submitted, you can wrap `Form` widget.

Comment: how can I use `Form` If I need to draw multiple textfields in a widget and this widget also created in for loop then I have problem of Global key @HemanthRaj can you help me out with this.

Comment: There are a way to know when user end type?

Comment: You can use a stream with debounce of 300~500 ms to know if user has stopped typing.

Comment: This is not working for me, it only shows the first 3 characters but print() shows the controller.text has the correct value.

Comment: Is there anything like onChange event ? How can we do so

Comment: I think there is on fro TextFormField not TextField. You can add listener as shown in above example to monitor changes.

Comment: It worked before but not for now with Flutter 1.22.4. TextField still work but TextFormField behave strangely.

Comment: Seems the `TextFormField` has onChanged callback. Try if that works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to transform the input to other form in TextFormField, you better use "TextInputFormatter". Using a listener with TextController cause a lot of troubles. Take a look at my sample code see if that helps you. btw, The last line of code is just trying to move the cursor to the end of text.

```
TextFormField(inputFormatters: [QuantityInputFormatter()])

class QuantityInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final intStr = (int.tryParse(newValue.text) ?? 0).toString();
    return TextEditingValue(
            text: intStr, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: intStr.length),);
  }
}
```