# Flutter TextFormField onChanged event

Tags: autocomplete, flutter

I want to build autocomplete using `TextFormField`, I don't know how to create OnChanged event for `TextFormField`
My requirement is there will be text field with some text, if user edits that text, textfield should behave like auto suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wrapping `TextFormField` in a `FormField` widget? If not, I suggest to use just `TextField` which has an `onChange` property

Edit: To set an initial value you can add a `TextEditingController` and asign it to the `TextFormField`

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

then in initState() you can do

```
_controller.text = 'Initial Value'
```

Comment: yes I am wrapping `TextFormField` in a `FormField` widget. Is it possible to set `TextField` value through code like `initialValue` of `TextFormField`?

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARS I've just updated my answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARS you can check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870082/managing-events-in-flutters-textformfield it may help you

Answer (score 4):

Lucky for us the onChanged option in the TextFormField is already available. If you update flutter and doesn't work just go to the text_form_field.dart file by clicking on the Widget TextFormField + command/control and modify the text with code in the link: 
[text_form_field.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/283ece3e92125de3078a29cadd58200b22b61f55/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart)