# Flutter update countertext

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, `inputDecoration's` countertext property does not change as the user is typing in the `TextFormField`. Is it possible to decrement the countertext as the user is typing?

```
TextFormField(
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
 decoration: new InputDecoration(
   counterText: "9",
   hintText: "Enter exact order number",
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870082/managing-events-in-flutters-textformfield) to work with your question

```
class StackEditText extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackEditTextState createState() => _StackEditTextState();
}

class _StackEditTextState extends State<StackEditText> {

  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  void onValueChange() {
      setState(() {
        _controller.text;
      });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(onValueChange);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          maxLength: 9,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counterText: "${9 - _controller.text.length}",
            hintText: 'Enter exact order number',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I do not recommend using the `decoration: InputDecoration::counterText`. You have to use `setState` or whatever to manually update the counter that way.

Instead, I recommend the `maxLength` property, that automatically makes a counter and updates it:

```
TextField(maxLength: 8)
```

Result:

[image]

This might be what most people want.

You can even further customize it with the `buildCounter` parameter, to return whatever widget you want when the text length changes. For example, if you only want to display how many characters left, you can do this:

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 8,
  buildCounter: (
    BuildContext context, {
    int currentLength,
    int maxLength,
    bool isFocused,
  }) {
    return Text('${maxLength - currentLength}');
  },
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very easy option - just a few lines of intuitive code.