# How to add user-submitted tags data from "material_tag_editor" into a "Flutter Form Builder" form?

Tags: forms, flutter, tags, material-design, flutter-form-builder

I am building a form using the ["Flutter Form Builder" package 4.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder/versions/4.0.2) and trying to add two fields where users enter "tags" via the ["material_tag_editor" package 0.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/material_tag_editor)

The Problem: when then form is submitted by pressing the "Post" button, neither of the data submitted for those "tag" form fields (Q1 or Q3) is included (see screenshot of the console below).

[image: console screenshot after submit]

Notice the line "flutter: {qFour: 30, qFive: sample answer to q5, qTen: sample answer to q10}" - neither Q1 nor Q3 are included (I added their data in separate print statements, so you see them in the console - look for the `>>>` lines).

Here are screenshots of the form with sample tags entered (iPhone simulator screenshot), and the bottom of the form with the button:

[image: screenshot of sample tags entered Q1 and Q3]

[image: screenshot of other questions answered]

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:streakers_journal_beta/screens/reviews_screen.dart';
import 'package:streakers_journal_beta/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:streakers_journal_beta/models/user.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

// BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
import 'package:material_tag_editor/tag_editor.dart';
import 'package:material_tag_editor/tag_editor_layout_delegate.dart';
import 'package:material_tag_editor/tag_layout.dart';
import 'package:material_tag_editor/tag_render_layout_box.dart';
// END code from material_tag_editor

//import 'dart:html';
//import 'dart:convert';

// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates, per https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html
class SandboxWriteReviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
  final String title = 'Material Tag Editor Demo';
// END code from material_tag_editor

  @override
  _SandboxWriteReviewScreenState createState() =>
      _SandboxWriteReviewScreenState();
}

// This is the private State class that goes with WriteReviewScreen
class _SandboxWriteReviewScreenState extends State<SandboxWriteReviewScreen> {
  var data;
  AutovalidateMode autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.always;
  bool readOnly = false;
  bool showSegmentedControl = true;
  //final _newFormbuilderKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _newnewFormbuilderKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  // above "GlobalKey" lets us generate a unique, app-wide ID that we can associate with our form, per https://fluttercrashcourse.com/blog/realistic-forms-part1
  final ValueChanged _onChanged = (val) => print(val);

  // BEGIN  related to FormBuilderTextField in form below
  final _ageController = TextEditingController(text: '45');
  bool _ageHasError = false;
  // END related to FormBuilderTextField in form below

  String qEleven;
  String qTwelve;

  // BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
  List<String> qOne = [];
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  onDelete(index) {
    setState(() {
      qOne.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  // below = reiteration for cons

  List<String> qThree = [];
  //final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  uponDelete(index) {
    // NOTE: "uponDelete" for cons vs. "onDelete" for pros
    setState(() {
      qThree.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

// END code from material_tag_editor

  //final _user = User();

  List<bool> isSelected;

  int starIconColor =
      0xffFFB900; // was 0xffFFB900;  0xffD49428 is from this image: https://images.liveauctioneers.com/houses/logos/lg/bartonsauction550_large.jpg?auto=webp&format=pjpg&width=140

  @override
  void initState() {
    //isSelected = [true, false];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_backspace),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                Text(
                  'back',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 7,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],

        leading: Icon(
          Icons.rate_review,
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'SANDBOX Write a Review',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 6.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'flutter_form_builder ^4.0.2',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.limeAccent,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 6.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // BEGIN appBar gradient code, per https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-improve-your-flutter-application-with-gradient-designs-63180ba96124
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigoAccent,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => FormBuilder(
              // was "builder: (context) => Form("
              key: _newnewFormbuilderKey,
              initialValue: {
                'date': DateTime.now(),
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                'Q1 via TagEditor', // was 'What are 3 good or positive things about the house, property or neighborhood?', //  [ 1 ​]
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: '  (optional)',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ), // was 'misleading or inaccurate?',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: TagEditor(
                        length: qOne.length,
                        delimiters: [
                          ','
                        ], // was delimiters: [',', ' '],  Also tried "return" ('\u2386',) and '\u{2386}'
                        hasAddButton: true,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction
                            .next, // moves user from one field to the next!!!!
                        autofocus: false,
                        maxLines: 1,

                        // focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        // ),
                        inputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
                          // below was "border: InputBorder.none,"
                          isDense: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            // above is per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5191
                          ),
                          labelText: 'separate,  with,  commas',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            backgroundColor:
                                Color(0x65dffd02), // was Color(0xffDDFDFC),
                            color: Colors.black87, // was Color(0xffD82E6D),
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTagChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            qOne.add(value);
                          });
                        },
                        tagBuilder: (context, index) => _Chip(
                          index: index,
                          label: qOne[index],
                          onDeleted: onDelete,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // END code from material_tag_editor
                    SuperDivider(),
                    // END Chips Input
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                '​​Q3 via TagEditor (skipped Q2, for simplicity)', //  [ 2 ​]  was '​​List up to 3 negatives, or things you don’t like, about the house, property or neighborhood:',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: '(optional)', //  was text: '\n(optional)',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              backgroundColor:
                                  Color(0x70DDFDFC), // was Color(0x30F8A0A2),
                              color: Colors.black54, // was Color(0xffD82E6D),
                              //color: Colors.black54,
                            ), // was 'misleading or inaccurate?',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: TagEditor(
                        length: qThree.length,
                        delimiters: [','], // was delimiters: [',', ' '],
                        hasAddButton: true,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction
                            .next, // moves user from one field to the next!!!!
                        autofocus: false,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        // focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        // ),
                        inputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
                          // below was "border: InputBorder.none,"
                          isDense: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            // above is per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5191
                          ),
                          labelText: 'separate,  with,  commas',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            backgroundColor:
                                Color(0x65dffd02), // was Color(0xffDDFDFC),
                            color: Colors.black87, // was Color(0xffD82E6D),
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTagChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            qThree.add(value);
                          });
                        },
                        tagBuilder: (context, index) => _Chip(
                          index: index,
                          label: qThree[index],
                          onDeleted: uponDelete,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // END code from material_tag_editor
                    SuperDivider(),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                '​​Q4 - via FormBuilder\'s FormBuilderRadioGroup', //  [ 3 ​]
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: '  (required)',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.red[700],
                            ), // was 'misleading or inaccurate?',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    FormBuilderRadioGroup(
                      name: 'qFour',
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                      wrapVerticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                      // orientation: GroupedRadioOrientation.vertical,
                      orientation: OptionsOrientation.vertical,
                      onChanged: _onChanged,
                      options: [
                        FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: '0', child: Text('Never')),
                        FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: '30', child: Text('Within the last month')),
                        FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: '180',
                            child: Text('Within the last 6 months')),
                        FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: '181',
                            child: Text('More than 6 months ago')),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SuperDivider(),
                    Center(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  'Q5 - via FormBuilder\'s FormBuilderTextField', //  [ 4 ​]
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: '  (optional)',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                              ), // was 'misleading or inaccurate?',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GavTextField(
                      maxCharLength: 200,
                      fieldAttribute: 'qFive',
                      fieldLabelText: '',
                    ),
                    SuperDivider(),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                'Q10 - via FormBuilder\'s FormBuilderTextField  (skipped Q6 - Q9, for simplicity)', // [ 9 ​]
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: '  (optional)',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ), // was 'misleading or inaccurate?',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    GavTextField(
                      maxCharLength: 1200,
                      fieldAttribute: 'qTen',
                      fieldLabelText:
                          'Be honest & kind.', // was 'Be honest, but kind.',
                    ),
                    SuperDivider(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Colors.purple,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _newnewFormbuilderKey.currentState.save();
                              if (_newnewFormbuilderKey.currentState
                                  .validate()) {
                                print(_newnewFormbuilderKey.currentState.value);
                                print(
                                  '  >>> Q1\'s value via separate print: {$qOne}',
                                );
                                print(
                                  '  >>> Q3\'s value via separate print: {$qThree}',
                                );
                              } else {
                                print("validation failed");
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Post',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 200.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GavTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  GavTextField(
      {@required this.maxCharLength,
      @required this.fieldAttribute,
      @required this.fieldLabelText});

  int maxCharLength;
  String fieldAttribute;
  String fieldLabelText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      child: FormBuilderTextField(
        name: '$fieldAttribute',
        // BEGIN countdown to max number of characters, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035861/1459653
        maxLength: maxCharLength,
        maxLines: null,
        buildCounter: (
          BuildContext context, {
          int currentLength,
          int maxLength,
          bool isFocused,
        }) {
          return Text(
            '${maxLength - currentLength}',
          );
        },
        // END countdown to max number of characters, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035861/1459653
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText:
              '$fieldLabelText', // was "  Separate items,  with,  commas",
          //counterText: _textController.text.length.toString(),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.5,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
          ),
          //helperText: 'Separate, with, commas',
          //floatingLabelBehavior: ,

          // filled: true,
          // fillColor: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.05),

          // BEGIN change border if focus
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          // END change border if focus

          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(),
          ),
        ),
        textInputAction:
            TextInputAction.next, // moves user from one field to the next!!!!
        autofocus:
            false, // on screen load, first text field is already active - user can just start typing
      ),
    );
  }
} //</formstate>`

var alertStyle = AlertStyle(
  animationType: AnimationType.fromTop,
  isCloseButton: true,
  isOverlayTapDismiss: true,
  descTextAlign: TextAlign.start,
  alertBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ),
  titleStyle: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.black54,
  ),
  alertAlignment: Alignment.topCenter,
);

// BEGIN code from material_tag_editor
class _Chip extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Chip({
    @required this.label,
    @required this.onDeleted,
    @required this.index,
  });

  final String label;
  final ValueChanged<int> onDeleted;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chip(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
      labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
      label: Text(label),
      deleteIcon: Icon(
        Icons.cancel_rounded, // was "Icons.close,"
        size: 18,
      ),
      onDeleted: () {
        onDeleted(index);
      },
    );
  }
}
// END code from material_tag_editor

class SuperDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 4.0,
        bottom: 4.0,
      ),
      child: const Divider(
        color: Colors.white70,
        height: 30,
        thickness: 0.1,
        indent: 0,
        endIndent: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter form builder assumes that only form children's will be used which automatically updates ancestor form whenever their value is changed. But since tag builder is not a form widget, you can do two things -

1. Wrap these widgets inside a new form widget, whose responsibility will be to only send updates to the ancestor form and render its child.
   You can do something like

```
class GenericFormWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  GenericFormWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.attribute,
    @required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String attribute;
  final Function(BuildContext, Function(T value)) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, _updateValue);
  }

  void _updateValue(T value) =>
      _formState.setAttributeValue(widget.attribute, value);
}
```

2. Instead of using flutter form builder, you can have use Flutter form and create your own field UI using material widgets. This will be costly for you since you will need to migrate existing fields too.

Comment: Do you have an updated response for this using v4.x.x ?